# c# Math function not calulating

Tags: c#, math

I have a simple math function

```
    private int Doyle(LogArguments args)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round(Math.Pow((args.Diameter - 4) , 2.0) * (args.Length / 16),0));
    }
```

that should always return an int > 0 but my problem is if `args.Length` <= 16 it `args.Length/16` = 0.
I have tried:

```
decimal d = args.length/16
```

and `double d = args.length/16;`

which both turn out to 0 when Length <16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `args.length` is an `int` you are doing integer division regardless of what the type of the output variable is.  To force `decimal` division the simplest way is to specify a decimal literal in the denominator:

```
decimal d = args.length / 16M;
```

Or for a `double` use a floating-point literal:

```
double d = args.length / 16.0;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
double d = args.length/16;
```

> which both turn out to 0 when Length <16

That is because args.Length and 16 are both integers.  You get integer division (result 0), which is *then* cast to a double.  Instead, try

```
double d = args.length/16.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to multiply by a float value such as this:

```
5 / 16 = 0.3125
```

Then you should turn `(args.Length / 16)` into `(args.Length / 16f)`.

This will force the division to be does as a floating point, and keep any remainder. Without the `f` added, it will do it as an integer division which truncates the remainder, so any value less than 16 will be less than 1 and get reduced to 0.